# InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle. Trying to serialize a class with a member as IonValue to IonValue

Tags: json, amazon-ion

I have an object which has one of its member as IonValue. I am trying serialize the entire object to IonValue and I'm getting InvalidDefinitionException.

Serialization code which throws the Exception : **ionMapper.writeValueAsIonValue(CustomerClassObject)**

```
public class CustomerClass {

    private final String employeeId;
    private final String businessId;
    private final String customerName;
   
    private final IonValue eventVal;
    private final Map<String, String> additionalParams;
}
```

and my IonObjectMapper is initialized as below

```
public IonObjectMapper createJacksonIonMapper() {
        final IonObjectMapper mapper = new IonObjectMapper();
        mapper.setCreateBinaryWriters(true);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return mapper;
    }
```

Exception stack trace:

```
InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: com.software.model.CustomerClass["eventVal"]->software.amazon.ion.impl.lite.IonStructLite["symbolTable"]->software.amazon.ion.impl.SharedSymbolTable["systemSymbolTable"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1276) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._handleSelfReference(BeanPropertyWriter.java:944) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:722) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could look at `IonValueMapper`:

http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformats-binary/javadoc/ion/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/ion/ionvalue/IonValueMapper.html

> Direct serialization to and from IonValue fields is supported. The POJO can declare fields of type IonValue (or a subclass) and the direct value will be provided.

EDIT: `IonValueMapper` is a subclass of `IonObjectMapper`.

Comment: But IonValueMapper is not a subclass of IonObjectMapper ;).

Comment: @Vishwaram Sankaran what do you mean? IonValueMapper extends IonObjectMapper, making it a subclass of IonObjectMapper.

Comment: There are two versions of IonValueMapper, one extends from JoiObjectMapper and the other extends from IonObjectMapper.